# Definition of the light that is projected by a celestial body/luminary

Tags: the-sun, the-moon, light, definition

I'm creating an application which will simulate the light created by sun or moon on a 3d topographic map of Earth. Something like this:

[image: map]

Is there a word or definition for this light/light projection?

Comment: Can you provide a sentence that you'd use it in, as an example? That might help provide a better context.

Comment: We need some more details. Do you want spectral irradiance or just a mean value in the visible range?  Are you interested in irradiance magnitude, angle of incidence on the Earth's surface, etc.?    There are very powerful applications called Ray Tracers for this but it's not clear how much detail you're after.

Comment: What do you mean "projected" and "luminary"? The Sun's light is *radiated* and is called *sunlight* but when it reaches the Earth's atmosphere it is also *scattered*. The light of the Moon is mostly *reflected* sunlight and is called *moonlight*. The light of other celestial bodies is either radiance (e.g. stars, gases) or reflection (e.g. planets) and is loosely called *starlight*. The effect of illumination on an uneven surface is *light and shadow*. Which of all these are you after? For "a word or definition", this question (if clarified) might be better suited to [elu.se].

Comment: @zephyr:I don't know how I can use it in a sentence, I'm looking for this definition to be used as the name of my application.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: No I don't need or use irradiance in my app.

Comment: @Chappo: Thanks for the info. I might check it out.

Comment: "Lambertian reflectance" are two words I am typing right now.